# How to start MAMP sql server automatically on system startup

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

I'm doing some work with the SQL server included with the MAMP package.  I'd like to set up my computer so that the SQL server launches automatically whenever I boot up.  Does anyone know the simplest way to make this happen?

Many, many thanks,

D.

UPDATE

When I try using the LaunchDaemon file suggested by Macmade, below, I get the following errors:

```
110906 19:52:05 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
110906 19:52:05 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/ is case in$
110906 19:52:05 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
^G/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
110906 19:52:05 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
110906 19:52:05 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
110906 19:52:05 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
110906 19:52:05 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
110906 19:52:05 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
110906 19:52:05 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
110906 19:52:05  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
110906 19:52:05 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/Doyuen-Kos-Mac-Pro.local.pid ended
```

After this didn't work, I looked in some of MAMPs directories and found a script called startMysql.sh.  When I run this from the command line, it starts the sql server. Perfect. On the off chance it might work, I tried throwing this into a LaunchDaemon file, too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>mysql</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/MAMP/bin/start.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This didn't work either.  Also, strangely, it didn't seem to produce any message of any sort in the Console app.

I'm still stuck.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just figured out one possible solution to this problem. It turns out that the paid version of MAMP, [MAMP Pro](http://www.mamp.info/), has a simple 1-click feature to configure your system to launch the SQL server on startup. So, shelling out ~$50 USD to buy the paid version is one way to get this working.  It's not the kind of solution I was hoping for, but it got the job done.

Answer (score 4):

Open Textedit or Plain text editor in mac, Paste this in it

For Apache

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>info.mamp.start.apache</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl</string>
      <string>start</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Then create another file for mysql

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>info.mamp.start.mysql</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
      <string>--port=3306</string>
      <string>--socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock</string>
      <string>--lower_case_table_names=0</string>
      <string>--pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid</string>
      <string>--log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>YOUR_USERNAME</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

**Be sure to replace “YOUR_USERNAME” with the username for your account.**

Save this file as (or move the file to) /Library/LaunchDaemons/info.mamp.start.apache.plist and /Library/LaunchDaemons/info.mamp.start.mysql.plist, respectively.

**Folder to save this is /Library/LaunchDaemons/**

Open terminal, type

cd /Library/LaunchDaemons/
sudo chown root:wheel info.mamp.start.apache.plist
sudo chown root:wheel info.mamp.start.mysql.plist

Done. Restart you Mac

Ref: http://stringfoo.com/2008/08/25/tutorial-launching-mamp-silently-on-startup/

Comment: Future readers: In more recent versions of MAMP and MacOS these files will need to be slightly different.  For best results reference the following scripts for details: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh' and `/Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh'   Maybe even try to  just running those scripts directly.

Comment: I follwed your advice in case of /Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh (apache works fine), but the only difference I found was port. changed, but didn't help. I'm still getting "access denied" error.
Can you explain how to run those scripts directly?

Answer (score 2):

You may need a LaunchDaemon file.

Create a file named `whatever.plist` in the /Library/LaunchDaemons/ directory, and placed the following content.

Note that the permissions need to be: root:wheel / 644

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>mysql</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/path/to/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
        <string>--user=_mysql</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Macmade, thanks *very* much for the answer.  Unfortunately this didn't quite work (see my edits above). Any other ideas?